# Click add to insert another input field in php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I need to add another input field of type select if someone clicks add location as seen in my code

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <p><strong> location</strong></p></br />
<select name="location">
    <option value="location1">location1</option>
    <option value="location2">location2</option>
    <option value="location3">location3</option>
    <option value="location4">location4</option>
</select>
<a href="#" id="#newField">Add location</a>
<hr/>
</form>
```

I have a few more selects in the form tag but here is where i have a problem. i need to just add the field and not refresh any of the the data the person has added.Thankinging you for your replies.

Comment: Do you mean an option should be added? What should be it's value and what this has to do with php?

Comment: Do u need to add the select option using jquery???

Comment: i need the entire select to be added just below this already existing select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `clone`:

```
$('#newField').click(function(){
    $('select[name=location]:first').clone().insertAfter('select:last')
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZYwzH/)

Note that you should not use `#` in your id attributes.

```
<a href="#" id="#newField">Add location</a>
         //-----^
```